# Finding the value of selected item of a dropdown: Is this the right way?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to learn [`ember.js`](http://emberjs.com). I am using version `2.4.1`. Given that controllers will soon be deprecated, I am trying to stay away from those and doing everything in routes and components.

So I have a route and on that route I have a dropdown. What I am interested in finding is selected value of that dropdown when it changes. For that I am using `actions`. This is how my template looks like:

```
                <select id="ddlIconSize" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 100px;" {{action 'changeSize' on 'change' }}>
                    <option value="1">1X</option>
                    <option value="2">2X</option>
                    <option value="3" selected="selected">3X</option>
                    <option value="4">4X</option>
                    <option value="5">5X</option>
                </select>
```

I tried a number of things to get the selected value of the dropdown in the action. When I used this link: http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html, I got an error message saying `changeSize action is not defined`. Other examples I looked at made use of [`Ember.Select`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) helper which is deprecated.

Then I ran into the deprecation documentation on Ember.js website here http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select, and based on the example there I ended up implementing the action like below:

```
  actions: {
    changeSize: function() {
      let newSize = parseInt(jQuery('#ddlIconSize').val(), 10);
      //do something with the new size....
    }
  }
```

This works!

However I have two questions:

1. Is this the right way to do this? Is there another way of doing it? I tried almost all the examples I could find on the Internet but unfortunately none of them worked.
2. I have to make use of jQuery to get the element in my route. This creates a direct dependency between my template and the code behind (.js file). This doesn't look right to me. There should be a way to bind the values of the UI components to something in my js file. Given that I am quite new to this thing so I may be wrong in my understanding. I would appreciate if someone can explain why I am wrong.

Comment: +1 for the question which I stubbed upon while our company was migrating to Ember 2.0+. 
What we decided to do at the end was using an ember addon instead of implementing own solution.
We chose [ember-power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select), but there are some more, for example [ember-cli-selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-selectize) (mentioning these 2 because of high score on [Ember Addons](https://www.emberaddons.com/?query=select). If you still want to go with your solution, you can get inspired by how these guys did it ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Pavol. Appreciate the links. I will check them out.

Comment: Here are more links: http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select https://gist.github.com/ef4/8367f996eb7b57d1f7a5#file-select-hbs http://jsbin.com/febafarova/1/edit?html,js,output https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select . I suggest ember-power-select if you don't want to deal with native elements.

Comment: Thanks @locks. I will take a look at the links. However I would appreciate if I could get answers to my questions. It would clarify my understanding of the framework.